# Avoid giant cascading in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I feel like this is something that is solved by "deferreds" or "promises" that I've heard about in jQuery, but looking searching for related articles on that doesn't exactly show me what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to do a simple jquery function call (like `animate()` or `slideUp()`) then call another simple function when it is completed. Of course I know about `slideUp(400, function(){ //onComplete... });` but if you have a large cascade of animations, that can get pretty hairy pretty quickly.

Check out the following jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ue3daeab/

When you click the first button, you see the visual effect I want to acheive. However, I'm accomplishing it with "cascade hell," and the relevant code being:

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    //Cascade hell

    $("#my1").slideUp(400, function(){
        $("#my2").slideUp(400, function(){
            $("#my3").slideUp(400, function(){
                $("#my4").slideUp(400, function(){
                    $("#my5").slideUp(400, function(){
                        $("#my6").slideUp(400, function(){
                            $("#my7").slideUp(400, function(){
                                $("#my8").slideUp(400, function(){
                                    $("#my9").slideUp(400, function(){
                                        $("#my10").slideUp(400);
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

When you click button 2, all the divs collapse at once, which isn't the effect I want. I feel like I should be able to do something like this, but obviously it doesn't work. The relevant code for the 2nd button is:

```js
$.when($("#my1").slideUp())
.done($("#my2").slideUp())
.done($("#my3").slideUp())
.done($("#my4").slideUp())
.done($("#my5").slideUp())
.done($("#my6").slideUp())
.done($("#my7").slideUp())
.done($("#my8").slideUp())
.done($("#my9").slideUp())
.done($("#my10").slideUp());
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just target each item with a class? and delay each by the appropriate duration? You are doing the same thing each time, so this could be easily written in one line-ish

Comment: Use a (semi-)recursive function instead of writing out the loop!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simple array of ids to collapse, and then collapse them one item at a time?

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    var toCollapse = ["#my1", "#my2", ...];

    (function collapse(){
        var id = toCollapse.shift();
        if (!id) return;

        $(id).slideUp(400, collapse);
    })();
});
```

I edited your jsfiddle with this example too: http://jsfiddle.net/ue3daeab/2/

Comment: I could, but that's because I'm doing slideUps every time. What if my function is changing, as well as the arguments? See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ue3daeab/3/

If that was my original, doing a simple loop wouldn't really work.

Comment: @JeffS While that's true, that wasn't in your question. How could I have known that ahead of time?

Comment: sorry, the example I was using was just that, an example. It isn't at all directly related to what I'm trying to achieve, but it is related in how I want to achieve it programmatically. I suppose I want to "chain" functions as opposed to having "nested callbacks." Your example is still nested callbacks, you just use some recursion to reduce the over text and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: 
**UNTESTED**

```
$.each($('.item', '#container'), function(index, value) { 
        $(this).delay(50*index).slideUp(400);
});
```

This way everything doesn't try to happen all at once.